# Core Data concurrency `performBlockAndWait:` NSManagedObjectContext zombie

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord, aws-sdk-ios

I have a following crash report from my released app:

[image]

`synchronizeMyWords` method fetches the entities from database, creates private queue context with main context parent and finally saves results. All operations are in the background thread. This method being called every time app goes into `background` and `foreground`. Here is a simplified method:

```
- (AWSTask *)synchronizeMyWords {
  __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

  AWSContinuationBlock block = ^id _Nullable(AWSTask * _Nonnull task) {
    if ([task.result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
      NSArray * records = (NSArray *)task.result;
      NSManagedObjectContext * context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextWithParent:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];
      [context performBlockAndWait:^{
        for (NSDictionary * info in records) {
            [RDRWord MR_createEntityInContext:context];
        }

        [context save:nil];
      }];
      return [AWSTask taskWithResult:@YES];
    }
    return [AWSTask taskWithError:[NSError errorWithDomain:@"" code:404 userInfo:nil]];
  };

  AWSExecutor * executor = [AWSExecutor defaultExecutor];


  return [[self loadLocalWords] continueWithExecutor:executor withBlock:block];
}
```

As you see I am using [Magical Record](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) 3rd party library to manage Core Data stack. Here is a method of creating private queue context:

```
+ (NSManagedObjectContext *) MR_contextWithParent:(NSManagedObjectContext *)parentContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self MR_newPrivateQueueContext];
    [context setParentContext:parentContext];
    [context MR_obtainPermanentIDsBeforeSaving];
    return context;
}
```

You can check the whole `NSManagedObjectContext+MagicalRecord` category on github [here](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/master/MagicalRecord/Categories/NSManagedObjectContext/NSManagedObjectContext%2BMagicalRecord.m).

How is it available that `context` object inside `performBlockAndWait:` released before it escapes the scope?
I am personally not able to reproduce the crash, but a lot of my users (iOS 8.1 - 10 devices) are affected by this issue.

**UPDATE 1:**

Here is for instance same report on [blog](http://www.jamieq.com/blog/2013/09/02/a-frustrating-nsmanagedobjectcontext-lifecyle-bug/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data provides ample APIs to deal with background threads. These are also accessible via Magical Record.

It looks as if you creating too many threads unnecessarily. I think that the employment of `AWSContinuationBlock` and `AWSExecutor` is not a good idea. `synchronizeMyWords` could be called from a background thread. The block might be run on a background thread. Inside the block you create a new background thread linked to the child context. It is not clear what `loadLocalWords` returns, or how `continueWithExecutor:block:` deals with threads.

There is also a problem with the saving of the data. The main context is not saved after the child context is saved; presumably this happens later, but perhaps in connection with some other operation, so that the fact that your code was working before is perhaps more of a "false positive".

My recommendation is to simplify the threading code. You should confine yourself to the Core Data block APIs.

Comment: Correct main context is not saved; main context is being saved when app goes background. It is separate operation. `continueWithExecutor:block:` means that the `continuationBlock` runs in background thread. Task here is [BFTask](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-ObjC) subclass, via link brief description.

Answer (score 2):

I marked @Mundi answer as correct, because he wrote the general approach you should follow. Now, I want to share here how I debugged it.
Firstly, I learned that, it is available to turn on debug concurrency assertion in xcode.
You need to pass following argument on launch:

`-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1`

[image]

Now, in your application output, you should see log message:

`2016-12-12 01:58:31.665 your-app[4267:2180376] CoreData: annotation: Core Data multi-threading assertions enabled.`

Once I turned it on, my app crashed in `synchronizeMyWords` method (honestly, not only there. Wondering, why Apple does not include concurrency assertions by default in debug mode?).  I checked what `defaultExecutor` is in [AWSCore library](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSCore/Bolts/AWSExecutor.m) and saw this:

```
+ (instancetype)defaultExecutor {
    static AWSExecutor *defaultExecutor = NULL;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        defaultExecutor = [self executorWithBlock:^void(void(^block)()) {
            // We prefer to run everything possible immediately, so that there is callstack information
            // when debugging. However, we don't want the stack to get too deep, so if the remaining stack space
            // is less than 10% of the total space, we dispatch to another GCD queue.
            size_t totalStackSize = 0;
            size_t remainingStackSize = remaining_stack_size(&totalStackSize);

            if (remainingStackSize < (totalStackSize / 10)) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), block);
            } else {
                @autoreleasepool {
                    block();
                }
            }
        }];
    });
    return defaultExecutor;
}
```

According to their `if` statement, my `continuationBlock` was not guaranteed to be executed on `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT` queue. So, I created one shared `dispatch_queue_t` queue and call all operations on it combining with `performBlockAndWait:` CoreData method. As a result, there are no crashes now and I submitted new release. I will update this post, if I do not get any crash report with `context` zombie.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! It think this is useful for others.